# Visual Studio Team Services Support .Net Core?

Tags: azure-devops, .net-core

anybody knows if visual studio team services support .net core?

I can't build our .net core proyect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it support.

If you are using .NET Core RC1, refer to this link for details: [Deploy ASP.NET Core 1.0 apps to Azure web apps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/aspnet-core10-azure-web-apps).

If you are using .NET Core RC2, refer to this link for details: [Build and deploy your ASP.NET Core app to Azure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure).

Comment: The ".NET Core" task is still shown as "Preview" in VSTS, when is this planned to be RTM?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure DevOps you can also use preview releases of .NET Core:
[Build .NET Core 3.0 on Azure Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574113/build-net-core-3-0-on-azure-pipelines)