# Azure Pipelines: .NET Core 3.0: Can't publish

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-core-3.0

I am having an issue with Azure Pipelines. I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project. Yes, I know it's not supported yet, but other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574113/build-net-core-3-0-on-azure-pipelines) say you can do it by including the following in the pipeline script. I am not sure how to do that, however.

> - task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
>     displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0 (preview)'
>     inputs: version: '3.0.100-preview6-012264'

Do I paste the above in the following script? If not, where would I place it?  Also, I am on Preview 9 at present—is that supported yet?

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' 


variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I paste the following in the below script or where would i place it

You can paste following scripts at begin of **Steps**, like:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 3.0.100-preview9-014004'
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.100-preview9-014004'
    includePreviewVersions: true

- task: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
  ...
```

You can get it by searching `use .net core` in the search box:

[image]

[image]

> I am on preview 9 at present does that support it yet

The answer is yes. This task is used to install the .NET SDK, which supports the .NET core 3.0 preview [versions list](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0).

As test result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks leo for the detailed answer i dont no why it was down voted but thank u

Comment: @rogue39nin, Anytime. I also don't know who did the down voted. Some one may have some misunderstandings about the issue. Anyway, don't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `UseDotNet@2` task.  You can add it to your list of steps.

Here's an example...

```
- steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 3.x
    includePreviewVersions: true
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- script: ... etc etc
  displayName: Continue as normal, now that the .net core 3.x SDK is installed.
```

And yes, preview9 is supported.  So is rc1.  This step installs the latest 3.x version and includes all previews.  Once it's released, you can remove the `includePreviewVersions` field if you want.

For more info, the docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops

Comment: i dont see that task when I look at the far right task lists.

Comment: Try adding it to your yaml directly