# .Net Core 3.1 not yet supported in Azure Pipelines hosted agents? Getting NETSDK1045

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines

It's great that [.Net Core 3.1 is out](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-1/), but I'm not sure the Azure Pipelines hosted agents have caught up.

My YAML pipeline specifies:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

and the `dotnet restore` step does this:

> (_CheckForUnsupportedNETCoreVersion target) ->  C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(127,5):
>   error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET
>   Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 3.0 or lower, or use a version of
>   the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.
>   [D:\a\1\s\StatsNZ.BESt.DataService\StatsNZ.BESt.DataService.csproj]

works fine in .Net Core 3.0.

Are there any work-arounds, or do we have to wait for Azure DevOps to catch up?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574113/build-net-core-3-0-on-azure-pipelines have a look here

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> .Net Core 3.1 not yet supported in Azure Pipelines hosted agents?

No, Azure Pipelines hosted agents supports .Net Core `3.1`, but the latest .net core **`3.1.100`** is not currently installed by default in the Azure Pipelines hosted agents.

You could check the [Azure Pipelines Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019 image](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/releases/win19/20200116/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#net-core), the default installed latest version of .net core is `3.0.100`.

To use the .net core 3.1, you could add a [Use .NET Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) to install the .net core 3.1.100:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like you have experience in azure devops pipeline, I'm trying to implement sonarqube into the pipeline. But it's always failing because the java Jdk version is supposed to be 8 or 11. How can I change the java jdk version in my pipeline?

Comment: I got this error for version 3.1.2  
[error]sdk version matching: 3.1.2 could not be found  
Link to Image: https://imgur.com/a/qYeSnwV

Comment: There is no 3.1.2 SDK, it's just the runtime at that version currently.  The latest SDK as of this comment is 3.1.102.

Comment: When I try to use the `Use .NET Core` task to build with 3.1, that task succeeds.  But when it gets on the `Build Solution` task, it still can't see the 3.1 SDK and fails.

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT - I do not see a "Use .Net Core Task" listed in the available tasks. I tried classic and YAML, and neither has it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Add a step to install .NET Core SDK before calling dotnet build.

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 3.1.100
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

Working and verified with `ubuntu-latest`.

Comment: I have a job to install .NET Core SDK 3.1 (I copy/paste your code) and it returns: "Successfully installed NET Core 3.1.100 SDK".  The next job (depends from the first) still use SDK 3.0.xx and fails. https://alex75.visualstudio.com/Cryptocurrencies/_build/results?buildId=457&view=logs&j=ca395085-040a-526b-2ce8-bdc85f692774&t=8aac088c-bc37-5d41-cf85-af8ebfb740e5&l=13

Comment: This totally fixed my issue, and allowed me to stay on `ubuntu-latest`.

Comment: @Alex75 Same problem here, it seems to just ignore the UseDotNet@2 task and uses the 3.0 SDK, weird...

Comment: Strange, I have no idea why this works for some people (myself included) and not for others.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the image 'windows-latest' you should be able to use dotnet commands. I changed it from 'ubuntu-latest' to 'windows-latest' and it worked fine.