# Run a prerelease version of DotNetCoreCLI in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, version, azure-pipelines, dotnetcorecli

Is it possible to run a pre-release version of the DotNetCoreCLI task when writing an Azure Pipelines yaml script? I would like to use 3.0.1xx if possible to take advantage of [`dotnet tool update` installing the tool rather than throwing an error if not installed](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/pull/10205).

If it is possible, what would the syntax be to make a call like this use a prerelease version rather than version 2:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install -g coverlet.console
  displayName: Install Coverlet tool. This task will continue on error if coverlet is already installed.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build .NET Core 3.0 on Azure Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574113/build-net-core-3-0-on-azure-pipelines)

Comment: I was thinking the cli task ran separately from the sdk version, but looking at that answer and the one given here they are linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the following:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 3.0.101
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

possible versions: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases-index.json

reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops

Comment: How does the `UseDotNet` and the `DotNetCoreInstaller` tasks differ? Does only `UseDotNet` change the version of the `DotNetCoreCLI` task?

Comment: where do you see the `DotNetCoreInstaller` task? you are using the `dotnetcorecli` task, which just invokes the `dotnet` with a specific command, whereas this command is needed before your command to install specific version of the cli

Comment: I'm using the `DotNetCoreInstaller` task to install v2.2, so was wondering if it mattered for cli if either `DotNetCoreInstaller` or `UseDotNet` were used.