# Use a specific version of .NET Core with the Azure DevOps 'DotNetCoreCLI' task

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I'm creating a Azure DevOps pipeline, and I have a requirement to use .NET Core 3.1.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops), I can't see any obvious reference to the version of .NET Core that will be used with the `DotNetCoreCLI` task, so I gave it a try -

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  name: Dotnet_Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
```

This failed with the error `The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.`, but interestingly the logs state -

> Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x SDK/Runtime along with 2.2 & 2.1.

With this is mind, I again looked at the documentation and came across the `requestedMajor|Minor|PatchVersion` parameters, so I updated my task -

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  name: Dotnet_Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    requestedMajorVersion: '3'
    requestedMinorVersion: '1'
```

Sadly this also failed, with the same 'Info' statement as above.

Comment: Found a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574113/build-net-core-3-0-on-azure-pipelines

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`UseDotNet` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) seems to be what I need here, with the description stating -

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to acquire a specific version of .NET Core from the Internet or the tools cache and add it to the PATH.
>
> You can also use this task to change the version of .NET Core used in subsequent tasks like .NET Core cli task.

To test, I added a new task to the beginning of my pipeline, requesting .NET Core version 3.1.101 -

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 3.1.x
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

#### Important Note

If you use the `DotNetCoreCLI` task in more than one job, you have to include the `UseDotNet` task at the beginning of each of those jobs. This is mighty inconvinient and hopefully something that can be improved in the future.