# Build/Publish .NET Core 3.x application with TFS 2018 Update 3.2

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, publish

I have an application that uses .NET Core 3.1 but in .NET Core Build and Publish tasks, the dropdown menu offers only 'til 2.x version.
[image: TFS pipeline]

How am I supposed to use them or what workaround instead?
Simple CLI?

Thanks in advance

@Patrick
.NET Core Task is this right?
[image]

But how should be that different compared to Restore/Build/Publish that are aldready set up in .NET Core pipeline?

If that so, I guess I just need to set the command with my custom publish value:

```
dotnet publish myPath -c release -f netcoreapp3.0 --self-contained true -r win-x64
```

Am I right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest.
I updated the request with my answers

Comment: Hi DioBrando, No, it's a different task, not .NET Core. Which may not pre-install in your TFS server.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops . For UI, you could take a look at answer in this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/56602320/5391065

Comment: Hi DioBrando,  Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

That's not stand for .NET Core Version.  It's our **task version** in Azure DevOps build Pipeline.

> Tasks are versioned, and you must specify the major version of the
>   task used in your pipeline. This can help to prevent issues when new
>   versions of a task are released.
>
> Each task in a pipeline has a **Version** selector to let you choose
>   the version you want.
>
> *Source Link: [Task versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#task-versions)*

According to your TFS tag, seems you are using private agent. You could choose to pre-install your .NET Core related environment/SDK in the agent manually.

If you want to do this during the pipeline, you should use [Use .NET Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops)

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to acquire a specific
>   version of .NET Core from the Internet or the tools cache and add it
>   to the PATH.

Not sure which TFS version you are using, which may do not contain above task. You could choose to manually pre-install .NET Core related on the agent or download source of task code and package upload to TFS server or use 3-rd party extension instead.

Answer (score 1):

That's the version of the task, not the version of .NET Core.